# Disable multitouch on android

Tags: android, multi-touch

I'm doing a quiz game for android, and i have four buttons so that the user select one to answer the question, but it's possible to click in more then one button at a time. How can i disable this, the multitouch? Help me!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't go as far as disabling multitouch ( possibly by overriding some callbacks )

I would simply change the activity layout to use RadioGroup which buttons will be mutually exclusive.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html